# Sql Only String search

Tags: sql, string, oracle, oracle11g

```
with temp(name) as (select 'abc' from dual
union select '123abc' from dual
union select '1abc3' from dual)
select * from temp where temp.name  like '%[a-z]%'
```

why i am not able to get all the 3 records in output
, I am using Oracle SQL Developer 11g

Reason why i am using this query is : I want to check if Desired column Contains only String no Number and Special Character

Comment: What database are you using?  Please tag appropriately.

Comment: He is using ORACLE. he is using dual table.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are mixing SQL Server and Oracle syntax:

**[SQL SERVER Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=8dd0c3b9dbc773a6f6a06ab5aff88b14)**:

```
with temp(name) as (
      select 'abc' union all select '123abc'  union select '1abc3' 
)
select * from temp where temp.name like '%[a-z]%';
                                        -- [] is T-SQL specific
```

**[ORACLE Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=0464e11aac102007772840b913b8b26c):**

```
with temp(name) as (select 'abc' from dual
union select '123abc' from dual
union select '1abc3' from dual)
select * from temp where regexp_like(temp.name, '[a-z]')
```

Comment: can you let me know Oracle Syntax

Answer (score 0):

Fist, it is better to use `union all` rather than `union`, because `union` incurs overhead for removing duplicates.

Second, your `like` pattern is non-standard, supported only in SQL Server and Sybase.  In other words, none of your names contain square braces or hyphens, so none match the pattern.

Does this do what you expect?

```
with temp(name) as (
      select 'abc' from dual union all
      select '123abc' from dual union all
      select '1abc3' from dual
     )
select *
from temp
where temp.name like '%a%';
```

This is only checking for syntax.  It is not equivalent to your `like` pattern.

I speculate from the syntax that you are using Oracle.  If so, then you can use regular expressions:

```
where regexp_like(temp.name, '[a-z]')
```

Most (but not all) databases support regular expressions, so you can express similar logic in most databases.

Comment: your like clause is not matching the question like clause

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you are mixing concepts. You are trying to do a regular expression compare by using a normal `LIKE` operator. Secondly, you should tag your question with the database you are using. I am assuming that you are using `oracle`, given the `dual` table.

```
WITH temp(name) AS (SELECT 'abc' FROM dual
    UNION SELECT '123abc' FROM dual
    UNION SELECT '1abc3' FROM dual)
SELECT * FROM temp 
WHERE REGEXP_LIKE(temp.name,'[a-z]+')
```

Also note that using the `%` wildcard character will not work as you expect it to in a regular expression match.